# How do I write a regex in my Rails model validation?

Tags: regex, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5. I want one of the attributes in my model to fail validation if it consists of only letters or if it contains the pattern `"\d:\d"` anywhere in its value. I tried this

```
  validates_format_of :my_attr, numericality: { greater_than: 0, :only_integer => true }, :allow_blank => true, :without => /(\d:\d|^\p{L}+$)/
```

But when I create a new object

```
2.4.0 :018 > ab = MyObjectTime.new({:my_attr => "ab"})
```

It is not indicating an error when I query `"ab.errors"` for the field in question.  What's the correct way to write the regular expression above?

Comment: Try `:with => /\A(?!\p{L}+\z|.*\d:\d).*\z/`

Comment: Why do you use a language that does not document very well ? Either `validates_format_of :my_attr, :without => /\A\p{L}+\z|\d:\d/` or `validates_format_of :my_attr, :without => /\A\p{L}+\Z|\d:\d/` should work. And, who's to know if the the premade `numericality: {}` overrides  the `:without` or if it's an else condition. Also, don't you have to associate a message with the error?

Comment: @Wiktor, I tried, "validates_format_of :my_attr, numericality: { greater_than: 0, :only_integer => true }, :allow_blank => true, :with => /\A(?!\p{L}+\z|.*\d:\d).*\z/", but it still did not indicate an error when I set the attribute to "ab"

Comment: So, there is something else going on behind the scenes as [the pattern can't match `ab`](http://rubular.com/r/4cKIqz4v9L).

Comment: @Dave you are using new which never trigger the validation, either call save on your object or create a method to trigger the validation. Then only you will find the errros to respective model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and Foremost new method does not trigger any kind of validation on the object.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end

>> p = Person.new
# => #<Person id: nil, name: nil>
>> p.errors.messages
# => {}

new method does not trigger any validation on an object as it is not hitting the database to save the record. 
>> p.save
# => false

save method will try to create the record to the database and triggers the respective validation on the object.


>> p.valid?
# => false

When you hit the .valid? the method, it validates the object against the mentioned validation.

>> p.errors.messages
# => {name:["can't be blank"]}

>> p = Person.create
# => #<Person id: nil, name: nil>

Creating and saving a new record will send an SQL INSERT operation to the database.

Internal functionality of Person.create is Person.new and Person.save

When you are creating an object, it tries to create the valid record to the database and triggers the respective validation.

>> p.errors.messages
# => {name:["can't be blank"]}

>> p.save
# => false

>> p.save!
# => ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank

>> Person.create!
# => ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank
```

Secondly,  **validates_numericality_of** and **validates_format_of** are the different set of validation helpers which you have mixed.

```
  validates_numericality_of :my_attr, :only_integer => true, :allow_blank => true,
                            :greater_than => 0

validates_format_of :my_attr, :without => /(\d:\d|^\p{L}+$)/

This validation won't accept any such object :
MyObjectTime.new({:my_attr => "ab"})
MyObjectTime.new({:my_attr => "1:1"})
```

For more information you can take help from these validation helpers => http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html

Comment: I added your two lines, "validates_numericality_of" and "validates_format_of" but got the error "/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:477:in `load': /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/models/my_model.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)" followed by "validates_format_of :my_attr, :without =>"

Comment: I have tested it, should work for you. It's working perfectly fine for me. Can you paste here the validation you are adding?

Comment: Oh I forgot to cut and paste the ":greater_than => 0" from your answer.  So the console loads.  But shouldn't I see something in ab.errors if I run "ab = MyObjectTime.new({:my_attr => "ab"})" ?  I don't see anything currently.

Comment: new method never triggers validation , try calling save method on your object to trigger validation

Comment: MyObjectTime.save Call this method to trigger the validation

Comment: Thx.  There is still one lingering issue.  The value "3rt" (for example) is triggering an error.  Since this doesn't begin with a letter and doesn't match the pattern "\d:\d", it shoudl go through.

Comment: validates_numericality_of :my_attr, :only_integer => true, :allow_blank => true, :greater_than => 0 converts number to float and then check whether it fall to the regular expression /\A[+\-]?\d+\Z/. So I belive from your test cases you donot need "validates_numericality_of". You should only make use of "validates_format_of".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /\A([^\}\{\]\[@\s\,]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }
```

Comment: are you talking about replacing my "without" block with your "format" block?  If so, I did taht and get this error, "/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.3/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:17:in `check_validity!': Either :with or :without must be supplied (but not both) (ArgumentError)"